# cplex would not run on matlab due to invalid mex-file

Tags: matlab, api, mex, cplex, dependency-walker

I'm trying to use cplex on matlab but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error using cplexlp (line 256)
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\Program
Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1271\cplex\matlab\x64_win64\cplexlink1271.mexw64': The specified
procedure could not be found.

Error in cplex_example (line 12)
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = cplexlp(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,options);
```

I have already added the paths as follows:

```
addpath ('C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1271\cplex\matlab\x64_win64')
addpath('C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1271\cplex\examples\src\matlab')
savepath
```

My laptop runs on Windows 10 64-bit, my matlab is R2013a 64-bit and cplex is cplex 12.7.1 win-x86-64.

I saw an answer to a similar question and they said it must be checked by dependency walker. Dependency walker showed that a whole bunch of API-MS-WIN-CORE, EVENTING, SECURITY, SERVICE, EXT-MS-WIN-GDI etc. dll files where missing.

I looked at a few posts implying that these are included in Visual C++ Redistributable packages, so I installed all editions of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (both x86 and x64 just to be sure).

But I still have the problem. What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB R2013a is not supported with CPLEX 12.7.1 (see the [detailed system requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100)).  You'll either have to use a newer version of MATLAB or an older version of CPLEX.

Comment: Upgraded matlab to R2016b and the problem went away. Thank you so much!